# Ubuntu center doesn't accept ubuntu DVD

Tags: 12.04, software-center, dvd

I just wanted to install a disk manager with the help of ubuntu software center. To install this disk manager ubuntu asks me to insert the ubuntu CD/DVD. I inserted the CD and clicked on "Continue" (I translate from another language. Maybe it is another word, but I don't think so).

After I clicked on Continue ubuntu software center aks me to insert the CD/DVD again...but I put it already in the CD/DVD.

I also insert the same DVD with wich I installed ubuntu.
Maye some necessary further info:
Ubuntu Center asks me to insert:
Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS_Precise Pangolin_Release amd 64 (20120823.1)

The DVD's name is:
Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS amd64

Any suggesstions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Start `Software sources`. (You can access it from Software Center's `Edit` menu.)

Uncheck the CDRom option on the Ubuntu software tab.

Comment: That was as easy as pie. It worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Accept the answer, than, to can close the thread.